# AlarmManager in Android while app is closed

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver

I'm developing an app that allow to users to set some time. In every Time i would like to set a notification. But, the notifications, works only if the app is running.

This is my alarmReceiver

```
Bundle bu = intent.getExtras();
    int Code = 0;
    if (bu != null) {
        Code = bu.getInt("TIME_CODE");
    }
    Intent MyServiceIntent = new Intent(context, ServiceNotification.class);
    MyServiceIntent.putExtra("TIME_CODE", Code);
    context.startService(MyServiceIntent);
```

This is my service

```
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    Bundle bu = intent.getExtras();
    int TimeCode = 0;
    if (bu != null) {
        TimeCode = bu.getInt("TIME_CODE");
    }

    NotificationManager mManager;
    mManager = (NotificationManager) this.getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(
                    this.getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),
            MainActivity.class);

    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            "Nuovo messaggio da cura alert", System.currentTimeMillis());
    intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent1,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this.getApplicationContext(),
            "Le notifiche funzionano", "It is working....",
            pendingNotificationIntent);
    notification.vibrate = new long[] { 100L, 100L, 200L, 500L };

    mManager.notify(TimeCode, notification);
    try {
        Uri notification_uri = RingtoneManager
                .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(),
                notification_uri);
        r.play();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ECCEZIONE SERVIZIO", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

And this is a method in MainActivity that add a PendingIntent every time in DB.

```
for (int i = 0; i < TimeItem.size(); ++i) {
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra("TIME_CODE", i);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, i,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        AddCurrentPendingId(i, "Test");
        String time = TimeItem.get(i);
        int Position = time.indexOf(":");
        int hour = Integer.parseInt(time.substring(0, Position));
        int min = Integer.parseInt(time.substring(Position + 1));
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }
```

When i set a Time for a notification and i close the app, not arrived the notification. When i open my app, the notification arrives. 
Thank you

P.S.: I don't want to use a GCM service.

Comment: just for the record, what you are doing is not a push notification, all you have is something to go off at a set time. GCM is a push notification

Comment: Have you tried using RTC_WAKEUP as opposed to RTC?

Comment: @Guardanis Thank you for reply. i've already try it, but doesen't work